# setting rpi-gpio pin on high after running a python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess, gpio

I'm building a photogrametry setup with raspberry pi and stepper motor.
The python script runs fine, but i got a problem with setting a pin to high after the script ran through.

The stepper driver has an enable input, which diasables the motor with high input, so i set the pin (gpio26) on high on boot with pigpio, this works fine. While running the python script, the pin is set on low, so the stepper can proceed, after proceeding i want to set the pin on high again.

i tried following commands:

`os.system('pigs w 26 1')` and
`subprocess.call("pigs w 26 1", shell=True)`

for a moment they work, but after exiting the script the pin is set on low again.
It's like the commands are resetted after the script stops.

Where is my fault?

Thank you

Edit:
Here is the gpio related code:

```
import os, sys
import subprocess
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import DigitalOutputDevice as stepper

def InitGPIO():
    try:
        global step_pul                     #pulse
        global step_en                      #enable
        step_pul=stepper(21)
        step_en=stepper(26)
        print ("GPIO initialisiert.")
    except:
        print ("Fehler bei der GPIO-Initialisierung.")
        
def motor_step():
    SPR=40000           #steps per rotation
    step_count = SPR
    delay = .000025
    for x in range(step_count):
        step_pul.on()
        sleep(delay)
        step_pul.off()
        sleep(delay)
        
InitGPIO()
step_en.off()

for i in range(1):
    #camTrigger(1)
    motor_step()   

#os.system('sudo -u root -S pigs w 26 1')
subprocess.call("pigs w 26 1", shell=True)
```

When i type `pigs w 26 1` in the shell, it works...

Comment: Please show more of your script – in particular everything related to GPIO handling.

Comment: Right - you never mentioned gpiozero originally. The docs for gpiozero say "In gpiozero, at the end of your script, cleanup is run automatically, restoring your GPIO pins to the state they were found."

Comment: Ok, thank you! But when they are restored to the state they were found, then the pin must be on high again after running the script, because its set on high after booting, so also at starting of the script. Anyway tomorrow i'll test with RPi.GPIO.

Comment: I don't think you should mix and match pigs with gpiozero - just use one..?

Comment: But the script is not running the whole time, so i need to set the pin on high, for the time the script is not active. Is there any other possibility than pigs?

Comment: Well, alright, it seems gpiozero only resets the pins _it_ touches – so if you don't touch pin 26 with gpiozero (i.e. replace `step_en.off()` with `pigs w 26 0` and don't even initialize `step_en`), would that do the trick?

Comment: That worked!!! You are my  hero. Sometimes it can be that easy. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my comment an answer:

Gpiozero only resets the pins it touches, so if you don't initialize or touch pin 26 with gpiozero (i.e. replace `step_en.off()` with `pigs w 26 0` and don't even initialize step_en), it shouldn't also reset the pin:

```
import os
import time

import gpiozero

step_pul = gpiozero.DigitalOutputDevice(21)


def motor_step():
    SPR = 40000  # steps per rotation
    step_count = SPR
    delay = .000025
    for x in range(step_count):
        step_pul.on()
        time.sleep(delay)
        step_pul.off()
        time.sleep(delay)


# Enable motor
os.system("pigs w 26 0")

for i in range(1):
    # camTrigger(1)
    motor_step()

# Disable motor
os.system("pigs w 26 1")
```